# Issue with git-push, Maven Release Plugin, and authentication between pom and settings.xml file

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, cicd, maven-release-plugin

I'm having an issue with authentication for maven release plugin that I've been dealing with for a bit. *I'm trying to hide credentials by putting them in the settings.xml file, but it fails to authenticate after versioning and pushing back to the repo.*

The documentation has stated to put the following:

```
> <properties>   
<project.scm.id>azure</project.scm.id> 
</properties>
```

However, I have tried this by putting it before the release plugin, yet have not had any luck... I then tried to put:

azure

within the plugin section as stated in the POM file.

POM file:

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
            <serverId>azure</serverId>
            <url>https://visualstudio.com/repo</url>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            <remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>
            <suppressCommitBeforeTag>false</suppressCommitBeforeTag>
            <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
            <preparationGoals>clean package</preparationGoals>
            <goals>deploy</goals>
            <generateReleasePoms>false</generateReleasePoms>
            <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I've referenced the "serverID" tag for the settings.xml file which seems to be giving the main issue and causing the authentication to fail.

Settings.xml:

```
        <server>
            <id>azure</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>somepass</password>
        </server>
```

Error I'm getting from Jenkins:

> > [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M4:branch
> > (default-cli) on project parent: Unable to commit files [ERROR]
> > Provider message: [ERROR] The git-push command failed. [ERROR] Command
> > output: [ERROR] fatal: Authentication failed for
> > 'https://.visualstudio.com/repo' [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR]
> > To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> > switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
> > logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
> > possible solutions, please read the following articles:

There isn't a ton of documentation on maven release plugin, and I'm not exactly sure how to map an ID from a POM file plugin to a "ID" in settings.xml successfully. Any help is appreciated.

We currently use the settings.xml file for nexus and works. From the logs:

> Executing Maven: -B -f
> /app/servers/jenkins/jobs/app-release-branch-generate-branch2/workspace/pom.xml
> -Dmaven.repo.local=/app/servers/jenkins/jobs/app-release-branch-generate-branch2/workspace/.repository
> -s ***/app/conf/settings.xml*** release:branch -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DreleaseVersion=test234-RC1-SNAPSHOT -DbranchName=test234 -DdevelopmentVersion=trunk-SNAPSHOT

It is referencing the correct settings.xml location within the log as shown above

Comment: Why using an old version of maven-release-plugin ? (https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/)

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using that settings.xml that you created? Please add your pipeline code to the question. Without the code it would be just guessing.

Comment: We currently use it for nexus. From the logs however::

Executing Maven:  -B -f /app/servers/jenkins/jobs/app-release-branch-generate-branch2/workspace/pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/app/servers/jenkins/jobs/app-release-branch-generate-branch2/workspace/.repository -s /app/conf/settings.xml release:branch -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DreleaseVersion=test234-RC1-SNAPSHOT -DbranchName=test234 -DdevelopmentVersion=trunk-SNAPSHOT


It is referencing the correct settings.xml location within the log.